# Hackerrank regex solution

Tags: java, programming-challenge, regex

I solved the following problem on [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/html-attributes).

The challenge is to:

> Parse HTML input and display the tags and attributes in lexicographically ascending order.

This is the input format:

```
2 //number of test cases/ lines of html
<p><a href="http://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial/html_links.cfm">Example Link</a></p>
<div class="more-info"><a href="http://www.quackit.com/html/examples/html_links_examples.cfm">More Link Examples...</a></div>
```

This is the output format:

```
tag-1:attribute-1,attribute-2,attribute-3....
tag-2:attribute-1,attribute-2,attribute-3....
tag-3:attribute-1,attribute-2,attribute-3....
...
tag-n:attribute-1,attribute-2,attribute-3....
```

Example solution:

```
a:href
div:class
p:
```

I am trying to get better at writing meaningful code for my solutions. Any comments/suggestions?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

private static StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
private static Pattern rgxForTagAtEnd = Pattern.compile("(<[a-z0-9]+)$");
private static Pattern rgxForTagAtStart = Pattern.compile("^[a-z0-9]+");
private static Pattern rgxToExtractTags = Pattern.compile("(<[a-z]+[^>]*>)");
private static Pattern rgxToExtractTagName = Pattern.compile("(?:<)[a-z0-9]+");
private static Pattern rgxToExtractAttribute = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+(?:=[\"\'])");

public static boolean checkForBeginningOfTag(){
    Matcher beginningOfTag = rgxForTagAtEnd.matcher(htmlBuilder.toString());
    Boolean B = beginningOfTag.find();
    return B;
}

public static boolean doesTagEndInTheSameLine(String remainingHtml){
    Matcher endingOfTag = rgxForTagAtStart.matcher(remainingHtml);
    Boolean B = endingOfTag.find();
    return B;
}

public static void printTagsAndAttributes(){
    Matcher M = rgxToExtractTags.matcher(htmlBuilder.toString());
    Map<String,TreeSet<String>> tagsAndAttributes = new TreeMap<String,TreeSet<String>>();
    while(M.find()){
        String tag = M.group();
        Matcher tagName = rgxToExtractTagName.matcher(tag);
        Matcher attrName = rgxToExtractAttribute.matcher(tag);
        TreeSet<String> attributes = new TreeSet<String>();
        while(attrName.find()){
            attributes.add(attrName.group(0));
        }
        while(tagName.find()){
            String nameOfTag = tagName.group(0);
            if(tagsAndAttributes.containsKey(nameOfTag)){
                TreeSet<String> tmpSet = new TreeSet<String>(tagsAndAttributes.get(nameOfTag));
                tmpSet.addAll(attributes);
                tagsAndAttributes.put(nameOfTag,tmpSet);
            }else{
                tagsAndAttributes.put(tagName.group(),attributes);
            }
        }
    }

    for(String tag: tagsAndAttributes.keySet()){
        String result = "";
        result = result + tag.substring(1,tag.length()) + ":";
        for(String attribute: tagsAndAttributes.get(tag)){
            result+=attribute.substring(0,attribute.length()-2)+",";
        }
        if(result.charAt(result.length()-1) == ','){
            System.out.print(result.substring(0,result.length()-1));
        }else{
            System.out.print(result);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
        if(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
            if(checkForBeginningOfTag()){
                if(!doesTagEndInTheSameLine(nextLine)){
                    htmlBuilder.append(" ");
                }
            }
            htmlBuilder.append(nextLine);
        }
    }

    printTagsAndAttributes();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Single-character variable names when used outside of 'traditional' loop constructs (e.g. `i`, `j`) or lambda bodies are <s>bad</s> not recommended, ***U***(ppercase) case ones especially more so as they can get easily be confused with class names or generic type declaration (the usage most often seen). Therefore, please give better names to `Matcher M` and `int T`.

```
public static boolean doesTagEndInTheSameLine(String remainingHtml){
    Matcher endingOfTag = rgxForTagAtStart.matcher(remainingHtml);
    Boolean B = endingOfTag.find();
    return B;
}
```

I think a primitive `boolean` will do here. The whole method body can be simplified to just:

```
public static boolean doesTagEndInTheSameLine(String remainingHtml) {
    return rgxForTagAtStart.matcher(remainingHtml).find();
}
```

One more thing: You can do with more white spaces between operators...